# Ввод ascii кода в emacs

Tags: кодировка, ascii, emacs

Как в emacs вводить не только символы, но и коды вроде \n \0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C-q` (команда `quoted-insert`), ввести номер, и `RET`.
Переменная `read-quoted-char-radix` определяет в какой системе счисления команда будет читать номер, 8/10/16.

`(setq read-quoted-char-radix 10)`
`C-q` `10` `RET` вставит перенос (`'\n'`)
`C-q` `0` `RET` вставит `^@` (`'\0'`)
`C-q` `955` `RET` вставит `λ` (лямбда)

`C-x 8 RET` (команда `insert-char`) также позволяет ввести символ по его номеру, или имени (которое Emacs может дополнить).

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как нашел, что нужно нажать `ctrl+shift u` и ввести hex код. И вроде как работает